# Not able to read Set-Cookie response header

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, cookies

Here is my api call, I am trying to read Set-Cookie from response header

```
 return $http(config).then(function (response) {
      console.log(response.headers('Set-Cookie')); // undefined
      console.log($cookies.ovrcMfa); // undefined
    return response.data;
  });
```

and response header is:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true 

Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, Set-Cookie, X-Requested-With, X-Session-Id, X-App-version, X-Target-Client, X-Origin-Domain, X-Dev-Mode

Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Set-Cookie

Set-Cookie : ovrc-mfa=IHfpt06ogxzLQFpwySE7vaJYg7whQ0sF; Max-Age=31536000; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 16 Jan 2020 09:30:47 GMT
```

Here I want to read Set-Cookie value ie ovrc-mfa

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(response.headers)`?

Comment: if I do console.log(response.headers('Set-Cookie')) it is undefined
and if console.log(response.headers()) it is logging request header values
and console.log(response.headers('Set-Cookie')) is logging header function's code

Comment: Can you show the exact output? Could you do something like `console.log(response.headers()['Set-Cookie'])`?

Comment: console.log(response.headers) is logging 
ƒ (name) {
    if (!headersObj) headersObj =  parseHeaders(headers);

    if (name) {
      var value = headersObj[lowercase(name)];
      if (value === void 0) {
        value = null;
      }
      Return headersObj
}
and 
console.log(response.headers()['Set-Cookie']) is undefined

Comment: You said `console.log(response.headers())` is logging the request headers. Do you mean *response* headers? If so, is the cookie among them? What is the exact console output? Add it to your question. You should probably also try logging `$cookies["ovrc-mfa"]`

Comment: console.log(response.headers()) is logging request headers only and not response headers. I have tried $cookies["ovrc-mfa"] , $cookie.get(''ovrc-mfa) and $cookie.ovrc-mfa. All are giving undefined value.

Answer (score 11):

`Set-Cookie` is a [forbidden response header name](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-name). You cannot read it using browser-side JavaScript.

If you need to pass that information to your JavaScript, then you need to have the server use some other mechanism (such as a different header or part of the response body).

Comment: Is it the same for axios?

Comment: @Andres Yes, it is not depending on the library as all of them use JS ajax calls behind  the scenes.

Answer (score -1):

if you are getting undefined then make sure you have npm install cookie-parser and imported on your project correctly as I faced the same problem and solved it like the way I have described

Comment: The question is about browser-side code, not Node.js.